# REGEX: Transpose each word from a google sheet cell and put them one under the other (rows)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, regex-replace

I need to extract each word (phrase) within a cell in google sheets and put each one under the other in a column (row for each one).

[image]

I have a regex code that works when testing it, but I cannot do it work in google sheet the same code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",char(10))
```

[image]

or

```
=transpose(split(A1," "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: this answer does not meet all requirements as it puts all results in one cell.

The ASCII character numbers need to be used instead of `\r\n` that you would expect from other tools.

Carriage return has number 13 and line feed has number 10:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\s", CONCAT(CHAR(13), CHAR(10)))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! But I need each word in an independent row of the spreadsheet. Is there any way to do it with regex? I do it by Split+transpose, but I think regex is to much better (I have a lot of info in the spreadsheet)

Comment: If you would like to keep the `\s` for detection of different types of whitespace, you can combine both answers - first replace whitespace with single space using regex, and then split & transpose.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex for this. You can use Transpose and split methods of google sheets.
Example:
In sheets in A1 put your text then in B1 copy this `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," "))`